# Is there a way to generate a text file for download based on form input using only Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I am new to Angular and am trying to make an Angular webpage which can generate sql scripts based on a form. However, I am not sure how my function for downloading the file would be like.

My idea is to call the `downloadScript()` function inside the button click event handler, but I do not know how to write it. Do I need to write separate backend code or TypeScript should be fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the complexity of your SQL, but a simple one can be achieved via TypeScript.
For complex queries that are dependent on other factors, you can do it via the back end through a post/get endpoint which will return the SQL statement.

There are a few packages available you can add to your Angular application to handle the file saving mechanism. I use these two below which work fine. The instruction is clear, you just need to gather the data and pass it to the saveAs function. You can as well specify the type for the text.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver/v/1.3.2

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesaver

When the user clicks on the button, a pop up will be open by the browser asking where to save the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for !